# Algorithms: Maximizing $\Pi \, a^{b}$ (NOTE: Homework)

Tags: optimization, algorithms

First I would like to say that this is a homework assignment, so I'm not looking for someone to give me a solution.  Just a little guidance if what I have is wrong or inefficient:

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, each containing $n$ positive integers, your goal is to reorder the value in each set such that $\Pi_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^{b_{i}}$ is maximized, where $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are the $i$-th value in each set after reordering. Design a greedy algorithm and show that it is optimal.

My first attempt is:

1. Loop through each list, storing $a[i]^{b[i]}$ in a separate list (call it `expList`)
2. Store `expList` into a list of lists (call it `listOfExp`)
3. Store the `list2` into a list of lists (call it `listOfList2`)
4. Remove first value from `list2` and append it to end of itself (essentially "pushing" each value up)
5. Loop through `listOfExp`, storing $\Pi \,a^{b}$ into a separate list (call it `listOfMultiplied`).
6. Find the index of the max of `listOfMultiplied`
7. Return `list1` and `listOfList2[i]`

I believe this has a run time of $O(n^{2})$: $O(n)$ for both the first and second for loop.
However, when I started thinking about it more I was thinking that another solution could be:

1. Loop through each list, storing the max of each list into 2 new lists
2. Return the new `list1` and new `list2`

The efficiency of this should be $O(n)$ (if `max()` is $O(n)$).

What do you guys think? Will either or these work? If not, maybe point out why and possibly suggest an edit?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I just realized that there is a problem in the first algorithm in step 4.  It doesn't produce all of the possible re-ordering combinations. For example, if `list2 = [1, 2, 3]` the possible orderings that step 4 produces are `[1, 2, 3]`, `[2, 3, 1]`, and `[3, 2, 1]`, however `[1, 3, 2]` is missing. Working on that problem now.

Answer (score 0):

First, forget about efficiency. What ordering of $A$ and $B$ would yield the maximum $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{b_i}$? (note that this is possible because all elements of $A$ and $B$ are positive integers).

Now, if you think such ordering is maximum, you need to proof it. The most straightforward way is to use contradiction -- you assume that such an ordering is not optimal. Then, in the optimal ordering, there must be elements that do not follow your ordering. Proof that if you swap these two elements, the resulting value is higher than the optimal value and thus, a contradiction.